Route Enhancer Problem with the TYPO3 Extension Event Management and Registration (sf_event_mgt)
I am using the route enhancers given here:
https://docs.typo3.org/p/derhansen/sf_event_mgt/7.5/en-us/ForAdministrators/Configuration/RouteEnhancers/Index.html for my integration of the extension "Event Management and Registration (sf_event_mgt)" from Torben Hansen. The extension is great but I do not get the routing with speaking URLs working (everything works fine without the route enhancers).
The events are listed in the view. When I press the button to get to the detail page of an event, it says "The event record is not available anymore.". A proper slug would be in my case "mydomain.com/event/myevent" I tried using different slugs for an event. Weirdly, when I use a slug which mimics a subpage like "mydomain.com/event/something/myevent" I can get to the detail page but again, the registration page for the event displays the same error. I cannot guarantee that there is no misconfiguration on my site, but I just do not get it work and my use case (website) is not that special.
I am using TYPO3 12.4.13 and sf_event_mgt 7.5.0. Let me know if you need any further information.
Update: Add site config
base: 'https://mysite.ddev.site:8443/'
baseVariants:
  -
    base: 'https://mysite.ddev.site:8443/'
    condition: 'applicationContext == "Development"'
  -
    base: 'https://testing.mysite.de'
    condition: 'applicationContext == "Testing"'
  -
    base: 'https://mysite.de'
    condition: 'applicationContext == "Production"'
errorHandling:
  -
    errorCode: 404
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: 't3://page?uid=69'
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    languageId: 0
    base: /
    typo3Language: default
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-de
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
    websiteTitle: ''
rootPageId: 2
websiteTitle: ''
routeEnhancers:
  ShowNutritionalInformationPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: myextension
    plugin: ShowNutritionalInformation
    routes:
      - routePath: '/{uuid}'
        _controller: 'NutritionalInformation::show'
        _arguments:
          uuid: 'uuid'
  EventListPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [57]
    extension: SfEventMgt
    plugin: Pieventlist
    routes:
      -
        routePath: /
        _controller: 'Event::list'
      -
        routePath: '/location/{location_title}'
        _controller: 'Event::list'
        _arguments:
          location_title: overwriteDemand/location
      -
        routePath: '/speaker/{speaker_name}'
        _controller: 'Event::list'
        _arguments:
          speaker_name: overwriteDemand/speaker
      -
        routePath: '/organisator/{organisator_name}'
        _controller: 'Event::list'
        _arguments:
          organisator_name: overwriteDemand/organisator
      -
        routePath: '/category/{category_title}'
        _controller: 'Event::list'
        _arguments:
          'category_title': 'overwriteDemand/category'
    defaultController: 'Event::list'
    aspects:
      location_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_sfeventmgt_domain_model_location
        routeFieldName: slug
      speaker_name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_sfeventmgt_domain_model_speaker
        routeFieldName: slug
      organisator_name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_sfeventmgt_domain_model_organisator
        routeFieldName: slug
      category_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'sys_category'
        routeFieldName: 'slug'
  EventDetailPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [58]
    extension: SfEventMgt
    plugin: Pieventdetail
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{event_title}'
        _controller: 'Event::detail'
        _arguments:
          event_title: event
      -
        routePath: '/{event_title}/ical'
        _controller: 'Event::icalDownload'
        _arguments:
          event_title: event
    defaultController: 'Event::detail'
    aspects:
      event_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_sfeventmgt_domain_model_event
        routeFieldName: slug
  EventRegistrationPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [59]
    extension: SfEventMgt
    plugin: Pieventregistration
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{event_title}'
        _controller: 'Event::registration'
        _arguments:
          event_title: event
      -
        routePath: '/save-registration/{event_title}'
        _controller: 'Event::saveRegistration'
        _arguments:
          event_title: event
      -
        routePath: '/save-registration-result/{eventuid}/{reguid}/{result}/{hmac}'
        _controller: 'Event::saveRegistrationResult'
        _arguments:
          eventuid: eventuid
          reguid: reguid
          result: result
          hmac: hmac
      -
        routePath: '/confirm-registration/{reguid}/{hmac}'
        _controller: 'Event::confirmRegistration'
        _arguments:
          reguid: reguid
          hmac: hmac
      -
        routePath: '/cancel-registration/{reguid}/{hmac}'
        _controller: 'Event::cancelRegistration'
        _arguments:
          reguid: reguid
          hmac: hmac
    defaultController: 'Event::registration'
    requirements:
      eventuid: \d+
      reguid: \d+
      result: '[0-8]'
      hmac: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}$'
    aspects:
      reguid:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_sfeventmgt_domain_model_registration
        routeFieldName: uid
      event_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_sfeventmgt_domain_model_event
        routeFieldName: slug


Did you add your PageId for the page-limitation? You could try try to remove the line: limitToPages: [21]

Yep - I actually already removed the line to be super sure.

Please provide us your complete SiteConfiguration. Else we can not see any problems with indents or interferences with other route enhancers.

Removing limitToPages is a bad idea, because there are multiple /{event_title} without a prefix TYPO3 has to guess which entry you like to get rendered. so to be 100% sure you need to add a prefix before /{event_title} or fix the limitToPages.
Furthermore what routes do you need exactly? I would start only with the detail view if I run into problems. This should be the most easiest route you can try out. Then fix the pageId and go for the next route.

Just added my site config. I added the limitToPages values once again but no difference in terms of behavior.

So I recently found the problem. The first route enhancer is propably misconfigured. If I remove it, the event routes do work fine.
